# Applying current date to equation in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using some aggregation to create a MongoDB view and for one property I want to provide a value which represents the number of days in which a document has been in a current stage. To do that I'm using a combination of `$divide` and `$subtract` operators, like so:

```
{ "duration" : { "$trunc" : { "$divide" : [ { "$subtract" : [ "$activeHistory.startDate", ISODate("2019-02-15T21:21:29.394+0000") ] }, 86400000.0 ] } } }
```

The one part I'm unclear on is how one gets the current date to apply in aggregation like this. What can I use, in place of `ISODate("2019-02-15T21:21:29.394+0000")` from the above code in order to get the current date for the aggregation logic to work with?

I tried doing this directly, with something like (but this errors out):

```
{ "duration" : { "$trunc" : { "$divide" : [ { "$subtract" : [ "$activeHistory.startDate", new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>") ] }, 86400000.0 ] } } }
```

Do I have to actually create a property assigned to the current date, and then use it in the next aggregation step I have above? What would that look like? My hope is that there is some MongoDB syntax available for the above kind of operation, where you need to get the value for the current date, on the fly.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23656

Comment: So, should I gather from that link that no such feature currently exists?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Hopefully in 4.1.